# Display user name from another table Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, listings

Hellow guys,
so I have 2 tables

1. is Listings
2. is Users

in Listings I have some columns, one is user_id, and is related to users tables.
I want to display the user name related to the user table.
in the index blade, I use some tags.
But when I use  `->rightjoin("users", "users.id", "=", "listings.user_id")` it's works but,
the join broke my tags make them default, same with others posts.

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $listings = Listing::where('is_active', true)->with('tags') 
            //->rightjoin("users", "users.id", "=", "listings.user_id") //don't show tags of the posts
            ->orderBy('listings.created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
                //check if posts ar listing by last date or something
$tags = Tag::orderBy('name') // variable displayed in view
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `with` method to get the related `user` like this

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $listings = Listing::where('is_active', true)->with(['user', 'tags']) 
            ->orderBy('listings.created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
}
```

but make sure that you add to your `Listing` model the correct relation like this

### Listing Model

```php
public function user() {
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this code for controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        return $listings = Listing::query()
            ->where('is_active', true)->with(['user', 'tags'])
            ->orderBy('listings.created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
}
```

In the models section, I suggest you put this code: ‌

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I suggest you fill in the fields foreignKey, ownerkey in relation: as in the following example:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```